# What trigonometric identity step am I missing with the following: (1+sinx)/cos x=(cos^2(x/2)+sin^2(x/2))+(sin2(x/2))/cos(2(x/2))

Tags: trigonometry

I may have to revise the question if I've made a mistake in typing it, but it should resemble the below pic, which is part of the solution for the entire trigonometric identity equation.

I only included the intermediary step as the entire proof for the identity is rather long. I just figured I would ask about this step because I cannot see how it comes to be.

I understand that cos x can be changed into cos 2(x/2). I understand that sin x can be changed into sin 2(x/2) by the same method. But, I am stumped as to how 1 can be changed into cos^2(x/2)+sin^2(x/2). I have a feeling it's a simple thing but it eludes me.

[image: textbook solution for problem]

This is one of the later exercises in the Chapter review I am studying on trig identities, so it makes sense that it is more involved as they want you to really think through the problems, not just solve them. So, even mistakes are informative, but I'd really like to figure this one out.

Comment: The first equality is just using a common denominator. The second simply uses $cos^2(\theta)+sin^2(\theta)=1$ and the fact that $x=2(\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: @Paul Did you intend $~\displaystyle x = 2\left(\color{red}{\frac x2}\right)$?

Comment: Oops, yes I did!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x \rightarrow \sin\left[2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]$$
$$\cos x \rightarrow \cos\left[2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]$$

$$\sin^2\frac{x}{2}+\cos^2\frac{x}{2} = 1$$

piecing this all together leaves you with the formula...

Answer (score 0):

It is a common identity that $$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1\:\:\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}$$
To prove this you can use their definitions in a right angled triangle and do the computations

Or you can use the fact that $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}2$ and $\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$

Answer (score 0):

It's a common misunderstanding:
Everybody knows:

$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$

... but many people forget this is true for every value (not just $x$, although $x$ represents just any value :-) ), so:

$$\sin^2(x+1)+\cos^2(x+1)=1$$
$$\sin^2(3x-8)+\cos^2(3x-8)=1$$
$$\sin^2(x^x+\frac{1}{x!})+\cos^2(x^x+\frac{1}{x!})=1$$

... and obviously, your example:
$$\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})+\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})=1$$